# Integer is returned instead of boolean in php

Tags: php, html

I hope you are doing great. I have a class in my project with various methods. The thing that happens is, one of the methods is supposed to return a Boolean variable. Instead. It returned the number "1" instead of false. If you could tell me where is the problem.

Thanks in advance, Cheers.
Useful pieces of my code:

Class method:

```
public function validatePwd($pwd1, $pwd2) {
    if (strcasecmp($pwd1, $pwd2) == 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The script that executes it:

```
$check1 = $user->validatePwd($Password, $Password1);
    echo $check1;
    if ($user->validatePwd($Password, $Password1)) 
    {

    }
    else
    {
       $errors[] = 'Error!, passwords entered are not compatible, Please'
               . ' enter passwords that match each other'; 
    }
```

Comment: A boolean cast to a string (e.g. `echo`d) will output `1` or nothing respectively.

Comment: Instead of an empty check then an `else` you can just use `!` (not) to do the inverse `(!$user->validatePwd($Password, $Password1))`.

Comment: Also... case *insensitive* password comparison...?!

Comment: @deceze I thought my comparison was case-sensitive. What is the case-sensitive comparison then?

Comment: When in doubt refer to manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php. This one is case sensitive, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php. You could do this all with ternary operator though..

Comment: Since the only thing you want to do is compare for equality... `===`

Answer (score 8):

If you do `var_dump($check1)` instead of `echo $check1;` it should show as boolean.